# Elasticsearch filter date range not works with before 1970's records

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am facing issue with date range,  Here is my query

```
 "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "(min..max).contains(doc.admitted_date.date.year)",
          "params": {
            "min": 1965,
            "max": 2015
          }
        }
      }
```

When i pass this query it was not work, it was showing all the results, if i am passing `"min" : 1971` it was working. This filter is not working with **1970**. if i am passing `"min":1958` and `"max":1969` it was working. when i include `1970`, the filter was not working. please help me out to fix this issue.

**EDIT :**

It will fetch the records from null value. If the `admitted_date` is `null`. it will shown in the 1970's records.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever... Why wouldn't it work with 1970 but it would with 1965?! And does not work.. any errors, something? Check firebug or something simular, there has to be something wrong..

Comment: i think it will index the null values as 1970 by default. because i have some data's with null values.